# Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку quzip в qt, вылезает много ошибок, как их убрать?

Tags: c++, qt

*Скопировал source files в папку проекта, добавил их в qmake, вместо define QUAZIP_STATIC у меня стоит DEFINES += QUAZIP_STATIC, при компиляции вылезает много ошибок как их убрать ?*[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавить в LIBS+= имя библиотеки (файла .lib (windows) или .a (linux))

Comment: добавил строку LIBS+=quzip.lib, теперь пишет :-1: ошибка: error: quzipfile.lib: No such file or directory,:-1: ошибка: [Makefile.Debug:130: debug/Archiver.exe] Error 1

Comment: Давайте так, вы на венде или на линуксе?

Comment: На windows 10..

Comment: Ну а файл у вас такой есть? quzipfile.lib ?

Comment: нет, я его не нашел в папке откуда брал source file ,  папку quazip вместе с source filre качал отсюда https://github.com/stachenov/quazip

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120262/discussion-between-razor0109-and-gbg).